Understanding conversion EPSG:4326 to EPSG:3857
I'm developing my own map rendering for the sake of education.
My problem: My data source is from OpenStreetMap in WGS84 reference. I'd like to project this data to Web Mercator projection (Wiki) so that my final image looks exactly like what OpenStreetMap and Google Maps renders.
My goal Get the projected values preferably normalized [0..1]
What is confusing me: In the wikipedia URL mentioned above, it states formulas required to get (x,y) coordinates for each lon,lat pair. My understanding is that if I define my zoom level to be 1, then the world coordinates will be (0, 0) to (1, 1) (as it states in the wikipedia)
However, when I define this formula in my software and plug in some values, I end up with some x,y values that are above 1.
Here's my function definition to apply the transformation written in JavaScript
function degreesToRads(degree) {
    return degree * (Math.PI/180);
}

function wgs84toWebMercator(node) {
    const ZOOM_LEVEL = 1;
    const PI = Math.PI;

    const x = (((1 / (2 * PI))) * Math.pow(2, ZOOM_LEVEL) * (PI + degreesToRads(node.lon)))
    const y = (((1 / (2 * PI))) * Math.pow(2, ZOOM_LEVEL) * (PI - Math.log(Math.tan((PI  / 4) + (degreesToRads(node.lat) / 2)))))
    console.log(x, y)

}

For example, given the lon lat (47.7843153, 29.4382474), the (x, y) values obtained from the formula are (1.2654684183333333,0.828743964602736)
We can see that the X value is beyond the world coordinates stated in the Wikipedia article.
